# PostgreSQL - cast to character(1) vs like

Tags: sql, postgresql

What has better (faster) performance?

`mycolumn::character(1)='4'` or `mycolumn like '4%'`

where mycolumn is text or character(200)

Comment: You shouldn't be using `character(200)` to begin with. See here for some details: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29

Comment: You could also use substring(mycolumn for 1) = '4' Why don't you find it out yourself? Simply create a statement and then check the execution plan

Comment: Performance is nonsensical. The DBMS has to retrieve 200 and more characters to inspect only one.

Answer (score 1):

It is often quite simple to do these tests yourself to see which is faster.

As a general rule, though, `like` with constants starting the pattern is index-friendly.  That means that it would generally be the preferred solution.

Even without an index, `like` appears to perform better, as [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fa0a89d9c980d98135daf3c6b51a07a5) in db<>fiddle shows.  Of course, working on this artificial data does not mean that it would have the same performance characteristics on your data.